# SQLite IFNULL doesn't work in formula

Tags: sqlite, isnull

Sometimes **SUM(c.Quantity)** is null so I need to convert it to 0, tried to use case/isnull and so on, but it doesn't work in this formula.

```
SELECT (t.LastMonthBalance + IFNULL(SUM(c.Quantity), 0) - t.Balance) * 100.0 / (t.EndMileage - t.StartMileage) AS Result 
FROM TripSheet AS t, Cheque AS c 
WHERE t.VehicleId = 8 
      AND t.Date = '2018-05' 
      AND c.VehicleId = 8 
      AND c.Date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31';
```

Comment: This query has more problems like: CROSS JOIN and no GROUP BY clause. `IFNULL` could be replaced with `COALESCE`.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What data are you running the query on and what results do you get and what results do you expect.

Comment: @juharr if SUM(c.Quantity) has values it works alright, but if there is no values in table i get null of overall calculations. As i assume it doesn't recognise 0 as value in formula.

Comment: No values in the table?  Then what would you expect `t.LastMonthBalance` to be?

Comment: @juharr  for example needed month formula (100 + 100{is sum(c.Quantity)} - 50) * 100 / (200 - 100) = 150. If that month sum(c.quantity) has no value it should be 0 and result should be 50. But in my situation sql throws NULL value instead of 50

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is not with `ifnull` but that **other values are null**.

e.g. running (where quantity is null):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tripsheet;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cheque;
CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS Tripsheet (VehicleId INTEGER, DATE TEXT, Balance REAL, EndMileage INTEGER, StartMileage , LastMonthBalance REAL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cheque (Vehicleid INTEGER, date TEXT, Quantity REAL);
INSERT INTO Tripsheet VALUES(8,'2018-05',50,200,100,200);
INSERT INTO Cheque VALUES(8,'2018-05-02',null);

SELECT (t.LastMonthBalance + IFNULL(SUM(c.Quantity), 0) - t.Balance) * 100.0 / (t.EndMileage - t.StartMileage) AS Result 
FROM TripSheet AS t, Cheque AS c 
WHERE t.VehicleId = 8 
      AND t.Date = '2018-05' 
      AND c.VehicleId = 8 
      AND c.Date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31';
```

results in **150.0**

Running with an extra cheque entry :-

```
INSERT INTO Cheque VALUES(8,'2018-05-03',25.00);
```

results in **175.0**

However, if other values are null such as LastMonthBalance then the result will be null.

So perhaps you want something like :-

```
SELECT (IFNULL(t.LastMonthBalance,0) + IFNULL(SUM(c.Quantity), 0) - IFNULL(t.Balance,0)) * 100.0 / IFNULL((t.EndMileage - t.StartMileage),100) AS Result
```

In which case :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tripsheet;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cheque;
CREATE TABLE If NOT EXISTS Tripsheet (VehicleId INTEGER, DATE TEXT, Balance REAL, EndMileage INTEGER, StartMileage , LastMonthBalance REAL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cheque (Vehicleid INTEGER, date TEXT, Quantity REAL);
INSERT INTO Tripsheet VALUES(8,'2018-05',null,null,null,null);
INSERT INTO Cheque VALUES(8,'2018-05-02',null);

SELECT (IFNULL(t.LastMonthBalance,0) + IFNULL(SUM(c.Quantity), 0) - IFNULL(t.Balance,0)) * 100.0 / IFNULL((t.EndMileage - t.StartMileage),100) AS Result 
FROM TripSheet AS t, Cheque AS c 
WHERE t.VehicleId = 8 
      AND t.Date = '2018-05' 
      AND c.VehicleId = 8 
      AND c.Date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31';
```

results in **0.0** rather than null, as the original SQL produces.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, other value was null. But to solve it I have to change query using LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY clauses. **SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT (t.LastMonthBalance + IFNULL(SUM(c.Quantity), 0.0) - t.Balance) * 100 / (t.EndMileage - t.StartMileage) AS Result
FROM TripSheet AS t LEFT JOIN Cheque as c ON t.VehicleId = c.VehicleId
WHERE t.Date = '2018-05' AND t.VehicleId = 1
GROUP BY t.VehicleId;
```

Thank you Lukasz and MikeT.